# How to fix input value different from console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, uuid

When using `console.log`, it generates **3** different values (**which is what I want**), but when passing the variable to the `input val`, it generates only one.

What I need is for the 3 (three) codes generated by my function to appear in the input value and not only in `console.log`...

```
function uniqueID() {
  function chr4() {
    return (Math.random().toString(16).slice(-4)).toUpperCase();
  }
  return chr4() + chr4() + '-' + chr4() + '-' + chr4() + '-' + chr4() + '-' + chr4() + chr4() + chr4();
}
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var id_unique = uniqueID();
  console.log(id_unique);
}
$("#input_test").val(id_unique);
```

Comment: cause out of loop `id_unique` have only one latest value

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're passing it a single value. But from the docs `.val()` looks like you can pass an array of [values](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). Also, what @demo said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @demo mentioned, you logging inside of your loop. This is why you see all 3 values. So `id_unique` on every loop is getting reassigned, thus on the final loop is only equal to the last value. The bottom provided solution pushes the current value into an array and then you can use that array in `val()`.

Try this, see if it gets you going.

```js
function uniqueID() {
  function chr4() {
    return Math.random()
      .toString(16)
      .slice(-4)
      .toUpperCase();
  }
  return (
    chr4() +
    chr4() +
    '-' +
    chr4() +
    '-' +
    chr4() +
    '-' +
    chr4() +
    '-' +
    chr4() +
    chr4() +
    chr4()
  );
}
var ids = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var id_unique = uniqueID();
  ids.push(id_unique);
}
console.log(ids);
$('#input_test').val(ids);
```

Comment: Using the array directly to set the input's value is possibly problematic... An idea would be to join the values with comas... `$('#input_test').val(ids.join(","))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked;)
I've been trying and trying since yesterday and I'm not going to go away, I'm going to study the code you used to understand why it's working. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Glad we could help, I've updated the answer with an explanation. Also, depending on how the values are used and displayed as @louyspatricebassette mentioned you can join the values.

Answer (score 0):

In for loop you have to save each generated value in different variable, your code now change the value of (id_unique) in each iteration, then it prints the last generated value.